# Error No Database Selected PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have read a bunch of the other posts about similar issues but I am very new to this so I am likely missing something. Most of the other questions I found were a lot more complicated than mine. I am trying to follow the w3schools tutorial for this and am testing locally using XAMPP. Right now I am just trying to get this to work successfully and eventually I am planning to submit data into a mySQL database from a web form.

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$dbname="mysql";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO owner_table (ownerFirst, ownerLast, mobile)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', '1111111111')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

NOTE:
The connection is not failing from what I can tell. Removing everything after the first if statement, and adding else { echo "success" } outputs success. Again though, I am new to PHP.

If someone knows that the answer has been given in another post PLEASE PLEASE comment here and ill close this out.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php   what makes you think you can just make up your own argument ordering for a function call?

Comment: No need to be rude. As mentioned I am new to PHP and was trying to follow w3chools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the proper syntax:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(<host Name>, <username>, <password>, <database name>);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php#refsect1-function.mysqli-connect-examples

Add two more parameters- **username** and **password** here:

```
$username = "root";  // Default values
$password = "";      // Default values

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that you had to have those defined since I didn't have those set for my database. Looks like that fixed it and I feel like a moron :D thank you!